# Interpretation of Kaplan-Meier Curve that doesn't go to 0

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, survival, curve-fitting

I'm making a survival analysis and I founded a little strange the survival curve founded by the Kaplan-Meier estimator. The curves are below

[image]

Here each colour represents a group and time is in days. The time of the study is 60 days.

Usually in most the examples that I saw the Kaplan-Meier curve goes to 0, but in this case $P(T>60)\approx 0.75$ for any group.

In this dataset that I'm using almost 90% of the times are right censored data, I think that can be the cause of it, but I'm not sure.

Is it normal?

I make the model following the format below

```
fit<-survfit(Surv(time,event)~ Group,type="kaplan-meier")
```

where event is 1 if failure and 0 if censored.

Comment: Whenever the last event is censored the Kaplan-Meier curve won't go to zero.  You know people are alive beyond this point but you have no way of estimating their chances of dying thereafter.

Comment: It's nice that most of your subjects survived--at least for them!  If you want full information about survivorship, then either follow them for a longer time or kill them off quicker :-).

Comment: @dsaxton For last event censored you mean right censored?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @dsaxton Is there a way to estimate the survival probability in certain time with Kaplan-Meier estimator? In this case for example I don't know the median, just that is bigger than 60 days.

Comment: That's all you can say about the median. This is the problem with heavily censored data.

Comment: @dsaxton, why not turn that into an official answer?